# Update of cell not showing correctly without manual enter

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code that does an update to a cell in a different sheet, however the cell value does not refresh the sheet values and appear correctly until I hit the enter key manually, how can I simulate the enter key in VBA.

VBA Code:
[image: Excl sheet]

```
Sub MassPrintSheets()
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ary As Variant, nary As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, rr As Long

    Sheets("Mass print of Serial Numbers").Select

    NumRows = Range("A1")
    ary = Range("B5", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).Value2

    For r = 1 To NumRows
        If ary(r, 1) > 0 And ary(r, 1) <> "" Then
            xSN = ary(r, 1)
  
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M4") = xSN
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O4").Select
            ' ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
  
            '  UpdateComponentList Target.Value
  
            'Sheets("Sheet1").PrintOut
            ' Sheets("A4 Despatch Label").PrintOut
            Sheets("Mass print of Serial Numbers").Select

        End If
    Next r

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Not sure what I need to do.

Comment: Is the file on "Manual Calculation" mode ?  If yes please try changing to "Automatic Calculation" mode.

Comment: The sheet is on Automatic calculation

Comment: This code in whitch sheet's module is in? You change  cell M4 in sheet1 but finally with> Sheets("Mass print of Serial Numbers").Select  ....... you select another sheet. So in whitch cell press the return? how arrive to that cell? Whitch cells in which sheet don't update?

Answer (score 0):

Simulating entering the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key can be done using `SendKeys`, as indicated in [this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys).

Comment: I have trued adding the Sendkeys, but that's not working either

Comment: On the change of the value in M4, it is running another another procedure successfully to extract the data (to a different sheet) but the values in the visible sheet are not updated (they are vlookup's)